# Custom parameter update in tensorflow not working

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I'm having trouble implementing my own parameter update defined below. I am trying to do this for a convolutional neural network that works when I use the AdamOptimizer. 
Showing a histogram of weight and bias values shows no change over iterations, despite a change in loss. Thanks in advance.

```
def gradient_upgrade(gradients, base_rate, rate_multiplier):

    with tf.name_scope('gradient-update'):
        for i in range(len(weights)):
            weights[i].assign(tf.subtract(weights[i], tf.multiply(gradients[i], base_rate * rate_multiplier)))
            biases[i].assign(tf.subtract(biases[i], tf.multiply(gradients[len(weights)+i], base_rate * rate_multiplier)))

    return weights, biases

gradient = tf.gradients(cost, [*weights, *biases])
```

Where I later call sess.run on feed_dict = minibatch

```
sess.run(gradient_upgrade(gradient, .001, 1), feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

weights and biases are in the following forms respectively

```
tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))
tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]))
```

Comment: Simply saying that it is `not working` is useless. Please [edit] your question to explain _what_ does not work. What do you expect? What does it currently do? What are the errors? Voting to close for a lack of details.

Comment: Hopefully this should make it a little clearer @MattClark

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that your assign operations are not executed. In your call

```
sess.run(gradient_upgrade(gradient, .001, 1), feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

the invocation of `gradient_update` simply creates the `assign` operations it does not execute them. Since the returned values of `gradient_update` are weights and biases, `sess.run()` executes the portion of the graph to get these variables, which simply means read their current values.

To execute assign ops, you have a few options. First, you can save the created assign ops and pass them explicitly to `sess.run()`. Another option is to use `with tf.control_dependencies()`. You can search for more [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies), but basically, it allows you to add dependencies between operations. In other words, you can tell tensorflow "before you can execute any of operations [a, b, c,...] you need to execute all operations in [x, y, z, ...]". Using it you can create something like an `update_op` created by `Estimators`. This update op will depend on all of your assign ops. Whenever you run `sess.run(update_op)` tensorflow will execute all of you assign ops.

Pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
# Create and put all of your assign ops in some list
# assign_ops_list.append(weights[i].assign(....)))
with tf.control_dependencies(assign_ops_list):
    train_op = ... # Some operations that should trigger assignments 

sess.run(train_op)  # all assign ops will now run.
```